# Model validation for any arbitrary model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Validation attributes in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` is very helpful in ASP.NET MVC 3.

There is a built in method called `ModelState.IsValid` which will tell me whether the current model bound to the view is valid or not, but want if I want to validate any arbitrary model that uses Validation Attributes. I am looking for a helper method that looks something like this:

**Pseudo-code:**

```
List<RuleViolation> brokenRules = ValidationHelper.GetValidationErrors(customer);
```

I know there has to be such a helper method in the System.ComponentModel namespace, or the ASP.NET MVC 3 namespaces, but I can’t find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should use [Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator%28VS.95%29.aspx) class to validate an object, or a property of it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [ModelState.Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.errors.aspx) property.  This should contain any model errors if the model state is invalid.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I am trying to validate an object which is not bound to the view.

Comment: @Broke - should still work if you use TryValidateModel or ValidateModel on the model object.